# Twitter Bootstrap: How to close modal dialog?

Tags: javascript, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm trying to implement modal loading dialog with Twitter's bootstrap. My current attemp is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#loading_dialog')
        .ajaxStart(function () {
            $(this).modal('show');
        })
        .ajaxStop(function () {
            $(this).modal('hide');
        });
});
```

Problem is that the dialog won't close.

Comment: Have you verified that the callback passed to .ajaxStop is actually firing?

Comment: @kinakuta yes, it fires and $(this) has the expected DOM element

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I didn't test it but the issue could depend on the context of the ajaxStart/Stop anonymous function.

Can you try this?

```
var loading_dialog = $('#loading_dialog');
loading_dialog
    .ajaxStart(function () {
        loading_dialog.modal('show');
    })
    .ajaxStop(function () {
        loading_dialog.modal('hide');
});
```

Comment: Any one please give us a proper answer.I am also having a problem.Not solved yet.