# After alert for file uploading close the modal pop up

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a scenario where I am *uploading* file using `IFRAME`. What I want is after succesfully uploading file, I want to close the `modal` pop up. But it is not working in my case. I tried like below

```
function CloseWindowFunction() {
        alert('PDF uploaded successfully');
        $('.modal-dialog').modal('toggle');
    }
```

Also see the html for the same

```
<div class="modal fade" id="dvFileUpload" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="dvFileUploadTitle" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">File Upload</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" data-keyboard="false">
                <iframe id="ifrmFileUpload" clientidmode="Static" runat="server" style="overflow: hidden; border: none" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So, how should I close that modal popup because my code is not working with `toggle` property.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get twitter bootstrap modal to close (after initial launch)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10495421/how-to-get-twitter-bootstrap-modal-to-close-after-initial-launch)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are calling CloseWindowFunction() inside iframe. If so then, please create a function say hideModalPopup inside parent page:

```
function hideModalPopup(){
   $('.modal-dialog').modal('toggle'); 
   //OR - $('.modal-dialog').modal('hide');
}
```

Call the above function hideModalPopup() inside CloseWindowFunction() like this. CloseWindowFunction() Edited, check below.

```
function CloseWindowFunction() {
        alert('PDF uploaded successfully');
        window.parent.hideModalPopup();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this

```
$('#dvFileUpload').modal('hide');
```

OR

```
$("#dvFileUpload .close").click();
```

OR

```
$('#dvFileUpload').removeClass('show');
```

Comment: where is `#modal` as ID in my html ?

Comment: Are you getting this alert `alert('PDF uploaded successfully');`?

Comment: after alert when I click OK, nothing happens. I have to close the modal box

Comment: Ok check this in console `console.log($('#dvFileUpload'))`. Are you able to access this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150781/discussion-between-vvvv-and-manoj).

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try with

```
function CloseWindowFunction() {
        alert('PDF uploaded successfully');
        $('#dvFileUpload').modal('hide');
    }
```

here for some reference for modal events
https://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a class with the first div of modal for example:

`<div class="modal fade test-modal" id="dvFileUpload" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="dvFileUploadTitle" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">`

and then call the

```
$('.test-modal').modal('hide');
```

Comment: i am using iframe, may be that's why it is not working